# Working with random integers

Tags: java, random

Here is the assignment:
For this program, there are two "parts". The first part will run the trials and determine how many caps each trial opens before finding a winning cap. Every trial (person) will be a winner. The number of caps opened by each trial is written to the file.
The second part of the program will read in the values and calculate the average. The average should be between 4.5 and 5.5 since there is a 1 in 5 chance of winning.

It compiles and runs, but the average is always 0.

My code:

```
  int randNum = 0; 
  Random randNumList = new Random(); 

  int counter = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many trials will there be?");
  int trials = in.nextInt();

  int winner = 0;

  PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File("cap.txt")); 
  //run trials
  for (int loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)    
  {  
    //select random number until 5 is selected
    randNum = randNumList.nextInt(6);
    for (randNum = randNumList.nextInt(6); randNum == 5; randNum++)
    { 
      randNum = randNumList.nextInt(6);
      counter++;
    }

    outFile.println(loop + " " + randNum);
  }   


  outFile.close ( );    //close the file when finished 

  String token = " ";
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("cap.txt")); 

  while (inFile.hasNext())
  {      
       token = inFile.next();
       if(token.equals("5"))
         winner++;  
  }

  double average = winner/counter;
  System.out.println("The average number is " + average);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Have you tried even compiling/running it?

Comment: What is your actual question?  "look at my code" is not a question..

Comment: It compiles and runs but the average is always 0.

Comment: let a poor op to answer why attacking the poor person?!!!! lol

Comment: @apsstudent you have to be more specific about your issue. explain your logic better or do something else cuz **it is unclear what is troubling you**. you know randNumList.nextInt(6); gives you number from zero to five?!!!

Comment: I dont think the program is selecting random integers

Comment: @apsstudent please try to post up your clarification into your post not comment so other can see. your logic does not make sense at all. at least to me. be calm and relax and break down your issue so let's us know what exactly is troubling you

Comment: Could you provide some context?  What is a "cap"?  What is a "trial"? What does it mean for a trial to "open" a cap?

Comment: I have to estimate the average number of bottles someone would have to drink to win a prize. There is a prize in 1 of 5 bottles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the int/int division accuracy problem which should be `winner/(double)counter` or `(double)winner/counter` try changing your inner `for loop` to a `do while`. In general, prefer `while` when you don't know the exact number of iterations.

Also, randNumList.nextInt(6) is [0-5], thus there are 6 possible outcomes -> there is a **1 in 6 chance of winning**. To correct this, use randNumList.nextInt(5) + 1

```
for (int loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++) {  
    //select random number until 5 is selected
    do {
        randNum = randNumList.nextInt(5) + 1;
        counter++;
    } while (randNum != 5);

    outFile.println(loop + " " + randNum); //why here?? maybe you should add it below counter++;
}
```

also `if(token.equals("5"))` won't work, as you write *(loop + randNum)*, it should work if you use `outFile.println(randNum);`

Answer (score 0):

Your cap.txt file doesn't contain "5" => winner = 0 and average = 0/counter = 0 (always).

Answer (score 0):

`winner/counter` returns an int not a double (integer division because both operands are integer so the result is truncated). Try this:

```
winner/(double)counter
```

That does return a double.

Comment: Thank you. I did that but the output was 0.04. what else Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `for (randNum = randNumList.nextInt(6); randNum == 5; randNum++)` with `while (randNum != 5)`.